# Select the values from Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, protractor

My code is

```
<md-option ng-repeat="item in countryList" ng-value="item" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_778" value="[object Object]" style="">
 <div class="md-text ng-binding">Afghanistan</div>
 <div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div>
</md-option>"
```

It is a Dropdown. Kindly help me to select all the countries one by one using protractor.

I have tried this

```
 element.all(by.repeater("item in countryList").row('1')).click();
```

Comment: Is there anything you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with cssSelector, repeater .. Did not work for me..

Comment: I code I have tried is updated above

Answer (score -1):

Try this, This should work.

```
 var countryList = element.all(by.repeater('item in countryList'));

    for (i=0; i<=countryList.length(); i++)
    {
             countryList.get(i).click();
    }
```

Comment: I tried with Repeater as well as the CssContaningText . Did not work for me.. Thanks for providing the code but it's not working for me..!

Comment: Received an error stating "countryList.length() is not a function"

Comment: No need to use `for` loop here.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `countryList.count()` for `element.all` array

Answer (score -1):

You can try by below way

```
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();'
var selectAllElement = [];
var countryList = element.all(by.repeater('item in countryList'));

    for (i=0; i<=countryList.length(); i++)
    {
             selectAllElement.push(countryList.get(i).click());
    }
    return protractor.promise.all(selectAllElement)
```

Wherever you will use this code, Please using .then( and next actions. 
Let me know if any issue.

Comment: Hi Yash, Thanks for your response, the code hasn't worked out for my case. I got the error stating                                                                                                    
      Failed: unknown error: Element <a ui-sref="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ManagePartner" class="ng-binding" aria-expanded="true"
>...</a> is not clickable at point (112, 361). Other element would receive the click: <md-backdrop class="md-select-backdrop md-click-catcher
 ng-scope" style="height: 1583px; position: fixed;"></md-backdrop>